# ACF fields value not available until saving post manually

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have some custom post type "video" and I added some custom ACF fields to it ("video_path", "author_name" and "audio_author"). I'm generating posts in that type programmatically like this:

```
$video_post_params = array(
  'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($video_title),
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_type'     => 'video'
);
$video_id  = wp_insert_post( $video_post_params );
update_field('video_path', $video_path, $video_id);
update_field('author_name', $video_author, $video_id);
update_field('audio_author', $audio_author, $video_id);
```

All values are inserted well - when I open the post in back-end everything is fine. However, when I try to use those values, I don't get anything?!?

I'm reading values from template files like this:

```
get_field('video_path', $video_id)
```

And if I open the post and just save it without any change everything starts working normally and I'm getting post ACF fields normally after that. Posts created manually, from back-end are working well all the time.

What I'm doing wrong? Do I need some extra step when generating posts from code?

The issue is reported here:
http://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/programmatic-post-insertion-acf-fields-and-the-save_post-hook/

But that solution is obviously not working for me - my `update_field()` functions already are immediately after `wp_insert_post()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it!

When inserting ACF field value field key must be used. If key name is used instead, as I did, everything is inserted well at first look, but value isn't available until post is saved manually. So it's like:

```
update_field('field_56e683ab6265f', $video_path, $video_id);
update_field('field_56e68415b5c4b', $video_author, $video_id);
update_field('field_56e6842d58740', $audio_author, $video_id);
```

What a mess....

Comment: Dear God :D really what a mess, was stuck on this exact stuff for 3 hours tnx much for sharing!

Comment: Nice one but unfortunately it doesn't work with sub-fields inside a Group field because "The Group field uses both the parent and child field names when saving and loading values. For example, a Group field named ‘hero’ with a sub field named ‘image’ will be saved to the database using the meta name ‘hero_image’." (see: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/). Do you have a clean workaround?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the field name instead of the field key, you can use [add_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_post_meta/)

For example:

```
add_post_meta($video_id, 'video_path', $video_path, true);
add_post_meta($video_id, 'author_name', $video_author, true);
add_post_meta($video_id, 'audio_author', $audio_author, true);
```

Comment: how would this work? I'm pretty sure it wont. You also need to update the field key.

Comment: @FooBar This assumes that video_path, author_name and audio_author are valid field keys. (Or, if you meant something else, like maybe you are thinking about using this in the context of a repeater, maybe expand what you are saying?) Note also: the fourth parameter (true) means that this will replace a previous value (if any).

Comment: This method is a good trick to deal with sub-fields inside of a `group` field, because you're supposed to concatenate the parent field name with the child field name to update them (e.g. : `update_field('parentfldname_childfldname', $value, $post_id);` ).    
I would suggest using `update_post_meta()` instead of `add_post_meta()` for more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as attachment instead of saving file path to database, acf work well with if it is saving as attachment id.See below code for example:-

```
    function get_file_upload_attachment_id( $upload_path, $post_id ) {
                require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
            
                // Upload file and attach to post
                $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( array(
                    'post_mime_type' => mime_content_type( $upload_path ),
                    'post_title'     => sanitize_file_name( basename( $upload_path ) ),
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                    'post_author'    => get_current_user_id(),
                    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                    'post_parent'    => $post_id,
                    'guid'           => $upload_path
                ), $upload_path, $post_id );
            
                // Set uploaded image as featured image (post thumbnail)
                if ( is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                    return false;
                }
            
                return $attachment_id;
            }
            $attachment_id = get_file_upload_attachment_id($upload
_path, $post_id) // first parameter is upload path
        
update_field('custom_field_name', $attachment_id, $post_id);
```

Now you can see it is visible in post page.

Answer (score -1):

With ACF5 you have to use not post id, but post object, lake that:

```php
update_field('field_56e683ab6265f', $video_path, $video);
update_field('field_56e68415b5c4b', $video_author, $video);
update_field('field_56e6842d58740', $audio_author, $video);
```

Comment: No, you don't have to use post object.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, and I correct it with simply add `do_action('acf/save_post', $postID);` at the end of the script, and that's all…